# Changing List Icons on Dropdown Hover

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, hover, icons

Beginner Question:
I have a dropdown list of 10, with black icons floating right.
I would like to replace these icons with white icons during hover.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create sprites. For example, if your Home icon is 32 x 32px in size, create a new image of size 32 x 64px and stack the icons on top of each other with the black icon at the top and the white icon at the bottom. If you do this for each of your icons then you'll be able to do something like this (please amend as needed for your own specific needs):

```
li {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    display: block;
    background-position: top;
}
li:hover {
    background-position: bottom;
}
li.home {
    background-image: url("images/home-icon.png");
}
```

etc. The benefits of doing it this way with sprites is that you don't have to ask the visitor's browser to load a new icon image when they hover over, which often causes a momentary blink/flash.

Answer (score 0):

use this css **list-style:circle** targeting the li element

Comment: Or you can use an image url in the css. list-style:url(images/round.png)